# Use rawEmbeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat when building Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, ios12

iOS 12 introduces a new property on AVCapturePhotoSettings where you specify the embedded thumbnail format for a RAW capture: `AVCapturePhotoSettings.rawEmbeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat`

In iOS 11 `AVCapturePhotoSettings.embeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat` is used instead.

Because iOS 12 and Xcode 10 are not out of beta yet, we build our shipping version with Xcode 9.x.

The Xcode 9.x compiler does not recognize the `AVCapturePhotoSettings.rawEmbeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat` api and so I cannot build it with an `if #available(iOS 12.0, *)` check.

Is there any way to tell the compiler to use the new api if run on iOS 12 without building with Xcode 10? Otherwise, our embedded jpeg workflow is broken on devices running iOS 12 beta..

Comment: Here is the developer documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/3019550-rawembeddedthumbnailphotoformat

Comment: How do you actually access the embedded thumbnail?